# Bind button click to set Icollection view source

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding, viewmodel

When my aapp launched i read a pricing file method attached to the soource using viewm-model approach then display it to the datagrid.

I'm trying to read the pricing file when i click on a button then attach the method to the view source.

I tried to set the view source on button click but nothing is displayed in the datagrid?  thanks for your help.

```
case "ReadPricing": //to read local pricing file
cvs.Source = GetProductsPriceListXML(); // method to read the xml file 
cvs.View.Filter = Filter;
View = cvs.View;
return;
```

**Button:**

```
  <Button x:Name="breadxml"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="62,10" Width="76"  Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="ReadPricing" Height="43" >
                <TextBlock Text="Read Pricing File" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </Button>
```

**Datagrid:**

```
        <DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
          Margin="0,2,0,0"   
          Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}, Path=ActualHeight}"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MianProduct" Binding="{Binding Mainproduct}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="*" />
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Visible" Binding="{Binding Visible}" Width="*" />-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Visible"  Width="100" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Visible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="NameIcon" Binding="{Binding NameIcon}" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**Datacontext/convertor:**

```
 <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ProductPriceViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MediaConverter x:Key="mconv" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

**Class-ViewModel:**

```
class ProductPriceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        
        public ProductPriceViewModel() { }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String info = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));

        private bool Filter(object item)
        {
            Product p = item as Product;
            if (p == null) return true;
            var ret = true;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MainProductSearch))
                ret = ret && p.Mainproduct.IndexOf(MainProductSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                p.Name.IndexOf(MainProductSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    
            return ret;
        }

        private CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
        public ICollectionView View { get; set; } 


        public ICommand MyCommand { get => new RelayCommand(executemethod, canexecutemethod); }


        string pricinglocalfile = @"C:\xmltest\Prices.txt";
        private void executemethod(object parameter)
        {
            switch (parameter.ToString())
            {
                
                case "ReadPricing": //to read local pricing file
                    cvs.Source = GetProductsPriceListXML();
                    return;
                    
                case "SaveFile":
                    data.Save("xxx.txt");
                    return;
                
                default:
                    MediaType = parameter.ToString();
                    break;
            }
            View.Refresh();
        }

        private static bool canexecutemethod(object obj) => true;


        XElement data;

        private List<Product> GetProductsPriceListXML()
        {
            var mylist = new List<Product>();

            data = XElement.Load(pricinglocalfile);
            foreach (XElement xe1 in data.Elements())
                if (xe1.Name == "Products")
                    foreach (var xe2 in xe1.Elements()) mylist.Add(new Product(xe2));
            return mylist;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't an `ObervableCollection` be better for your datagrid source?

Comment: @ChrisBD: Not sure but i have already dont with this approcah. thanks. Any idea call the view with button click? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I've not used it myself, reading through Microsoft documentation leads me to believe that `CollectionView` is actually a control that you can extend that allows you to manipulate a data collection within the UI without actually changing the data itself. It also doesn't appear to be used with `DataGrid` types but instead replaces them, specifically it expands upon or replaces `ListView`.

In this regard you need to bind your `ItemSource` to an actual data list e.g., `ObservableCollection<Product>`, whether you use a `DataGrid` type or a `CollectionView` type within your UI.

Thus I would recommend that you change the following:

```
    private CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
    public ICollectionView View { get; set; }
```

to

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList {get;set;}
```

This will automatically trigger a `NotifyCollectionChanged` when updated.

Then change :

```
case "ReadPricing": //to read local pricing file
    cvs.Source = GetProductsPriceListXML();
    return;
```

to

```
case "ReadPricing": //to read local pricing file
    ProductList.Clear();
    var list = GetProductsPriceListXML();
    foreach(var p in list)
    {
        ProductList.Add(p);
    }
    return;
```

or

```
case "ReadPricing": //to read local pricing file
    ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>(GetProductsPriceListXML());
    NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductList");
    return;
```

Then in your View

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

becomes

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

I believe that if you then wished to manipulate the layout or content of your `ProductList` at run time you would need to replace your `DataGrid` with a `CollectionView`, bind it's `ItemSource` to `ProductList`, finally creating a `ControlView` that presents a `CollectionView` type property and manipulates the presentation of the data - examples to be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/UserInterface/Views/CollectionViewDemos)

Comment: I forgto to mention i need sorting, filtering, or grouping so i'm using icollection.

Comment: Items = GetProductsPriceListXML();
View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
View.Filter = Filter;
View.Refresh();